# Ubuntu Apache2 PHP execute permissions

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, permissions

I'm having this problem in PHP using exec():

```
sh: CutyCapt: Permission denied
```

So, how do I give permission to the **apache** user or www-data user to execute **CutyCapt**?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you want to execute a script you should add excecute permission:

```
chmod +x /path/name/of/your/script
```

Answer (score 0):

Use chmod to add execute permission:

```
chmod +x /path_to_CutyCapt
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're using suPHP or the like, all PHP processes (scripts) are executed as the apache user.

This means any binaries you wish to execute from PHP must be executable by that user, as well.

What, exactly, does the error log say ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to set the user/owner to apache:apache or www-data:www-data depending on the user that Apache is running as.

Once you know what the username is for the Apache process, type:

```
chown <apache_user>:<apache_group> /path/to/CutyCapt.sh
```

Once you've done that, you've changed ownership of that file to the Apache user. The next step is to make the script executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/CutyCapt.sh
```